# Generating C# coverage report with AppVeyor

Tags: c#, .net-core, appveyor, opencover, codecov

I am using [this project](https://github.com/Elabar/osu) to practice my integration tool skill.
What I want to do is add a code coverage analysis in the CI.

What I have tried:

Use OpenCover to generate the report and upload to codecov. My appveyor.yml is shown as below.

```
test_script:
  - OpenCover.Console.exe -register:user -target:"C:/Program Files/dotnet/dotnet.exe" -targetargs:test -output:".\MyProject_coverage.xml" -oldstyle
after_test:
  - ps: |
    $env:PATH = 'C:\msys64\usr\bin;' + $env:PATH
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://codecov.io/bash' -OutFile codecov.sh
    bash codecov.sh -f "MyProject_coverage.xml"
```

Problem is:

I can see the summary result in AppVeyor, but I can't see anything at codecov.
[Result photo in Appveyor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mStOW.png)

Any help will be appreciated.

Note: I have gone through the [documents on AppVeyor](https://www.appveyor.com/blog/2017/03/17/codecov/) and [sample for CodeCov](https://github.com/codecov/example-csharp) and I still have no clue how to do it.

Comment: Is codecov.sh automatically made executable somehow in this? Really don't understand PowerShell so I'm not 100% sure what's happening. Generally though a script needs to be made executable before bash can run it; like `chmod u+x {file}`, which sets the executable permission for the user.

Comment: I opened your builds and followed report link from [this line](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/Elabar/osu#L450) and it pointed me to the [report](https://codecov.io/gh/Elabar/osu/commit/3c5b3c29dfa0548166b42fb31cc1f718f68b5230)...